# Requesting explanation of FitModel code

Tags: programming, function-construction

I am struggling with understanding the code given in this [original post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/testing-for-ols-heteroscedasticity-whites-general-test)

I understand how the tests are conducted, both of them. However, I do not understand this part:

```
FitModel[data_List, coords_List] :=
  With[{lm = LinearModelFit[data, coords, coords]},
    dispatch[{
      "BreuschPagan" -> BreuschPagan[data, lm, coords],
      "WhitesHeteroskedasticity" -> WhitesHeteroskedasticity[lm, coords]}]];
dispatch[list_][field_] := field /. list
dispatch[list_]["Properties"] := list /. Rule[field_, _] :> field
dispatch /: ReplaceAll[fields_, dispatch[list_]] := fields /. list
Format[dispatch[list_], StandardForm] := 
  HoldForm[dispatch]["<" <> ToString@Length@list <> ">"]
```

Could someone explain what this is doing? If you recommend that I do it in a chat, I have created a chat room for such discussion.

I find it particularly difficult to understand the code for `dispatch` and how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first few lines are self explanatory, they just build up a list of rules and wrap them in head `dispatch`. In this particular example the rules pertain to fitted models and particular test results but the `dispatch` mechanism is quite general.

Basically `dispatch` here is a way of creating a property extraction mechanism similar in spirit to that of [`FittedModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FittedModel.html?q=FittedModel&lang=en) with the key-value behavior of [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html?q=Dispatch&lang=en).

Lets start in a fresh kernel...

```
dispatch[list_][field_] := field /. list
dispatch[list_]["Properties"] := list /. Rule[field_, _] :> field
dispatch /: ReplaceAll[fields_, dispatch[list_]] := fields /. list
```

Here is a list of dummy properties to work with.

```
propList = {"P1" -> 1, "P2" -> 2, "P3" -> 3};
```

Notice that `dispatch[list]` will remain unevaluated unless a sub value is requested.

```
dispatch[propList]

(* dispatch[{"P1" -> 1, "P2" -> 2, "P3" -> 3}] *)
```

The `Format` statement is just a way of hiding this output so that if we had a really long list of properties we wouldn't need to see them all.

```
Format[dispatch[list_], StandardForm] := 
   HoldForm[dispatch]["<" <> ToString@Length@list <> ">"]

out = dispatch[propList]

(* dispatch[<3>]*)
```

Now lets look at what each of the previous definitions are doing. The first replaces the property 'field' with its value given in the list of rules. (*NOTE: As was pointed out by @Martin John Hadley this sort of assignment (via `SubValues`) is not often documented but you will find it frequently used for property extraction. Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) for a detailed discussion about this sort of thing.*)

```
out["P2"]

(* 2 *)
```

The second gives a list of field/property names contained in the `dispatch` object.

```
out["Properties"]

(* {"P1", "P2", "P3"} *)
```

The third definition allows `dispatch` to work like `Dispatch` by overloading `ReplaceAll` using [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html?q=TagSetDelayed&lang=en) creating an [up value](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpValues.html). Thus, if a list of properties is given we can replace them with their values contained in the `dispatch` object.

```
{"P2","P1","P3"} /. out

(* {2, 1, 3} *)
```

Comment: Andy, as they're not documented frequently is it worth making clear SubValues are being set in the first code block?

Comment: Indeed. I use these so frequently that I often take them for granted. I'll add a comment to this effect.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how Field is defined to have both "BreuschPagan" and "WhitesHeteroskedasticity". Cause I cant see where it is defined

Comment: Notice that the `dispatch` created in `With` contains a list of rules. The left-hand side of the rules are property names (in this case BreuschPagan and WhitesHeteroskedasticity) the right hand side are the values (here injected using `With`).

Comment: thats okey, but if I type Field, i do not get anything, but I was expecting to get ("BreuschPagan","WhitesHeteroskedasticity") since it is defined?

Comment: You should be using "Properties" not "Field". Also note that you need to use quotes.

Comment: Okey, Im going to give it one more go with this question if not I give up. As I see it {"P1" -> 1, "P2" -> 2, "P3" -> 3} /. (x_ -> _) gives blank because the entire {"P1" -> 1, "P2" -> 2, "P3" -> 3} matches x_ and is therefor transformed to blank by rule, which is then transformed to field in my code. And field is said to be ("BreuschPagan","WhitesHeteroskedasticity"), So thats why we get the output? What I dont see is where i have defined field =("BreuschPagan","WhitesHeteroskedasticity")

Comment: I've gone to your chat room. that might be more efficient.